# Which Team-decided punishments are you using for tardiness to daily Scrums?

Tags: scrum

Here is what the Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_(development)) on Scrum has to say about the Daily Scrum:

> The meeting starts precisely on time. Often there are team-decided punishments for tardiness (e.g. money, push-ups, hanging a rubber chicken around your neck).

Do you feel that it is a good practice and what self-punishment have you found effective in the past?

Comment: i think the only proper response for "you've got to wear this rubber chicken around your neck" is "make me, punk" ;-)

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's not within the scope for this site, as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](//stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) You may be able to ask on [another Stack Exchange site](//stackexchange.com/sites#name), for example [pm.se] or [softwareengineering.se]. Be sure to read the on-topic page in the help center for any site on which you intend to post a question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When I've been the scrum master we always started on time regardless of whether everyone is there or not. If people don't make it they miss out - no chance to engage with the rest of the team on their progress and blockers. In my experience, it only takes one or two times for that to happen and the team self polices - people know we start on time, finish on time, and if you're not there you miss out - no punishment needed, it's all done by peer pressure.

BTW set your scrum time the same time every day, and allow for people's work patterns ie - 9:00AM doesn't work for everyone, but 10:00 should do, even better go for 9:50, run for 10 minutes and you don't crash anyone elses meetings.

Comment: I totally agree. The punishment should be the shame you feel when the team begins to realize that you are not as trustworthy and commited as everyone else.

Comment: And if the individual doesn't care? If the meeting's optional, don't be surprised if some people opt out. If it's mandatory (and in a Scrum environment I think it should be) then it's a condition of continuing employment.

Comment: If people really don't care about missing the meeting, it may also be a sign that they're not getting as much out of it as they should. Should it be shorter and snappier? More relevant? Is there stuff happening there that should happen in a smaller meeting elsewhere?

Answer (score 6):

I think it's bad practice. My current employer schedules our weekly catchup (No daily meetings sadly) at 9am on Monday morning and hits the roof when people are not on time. Rather then getting irate and verbally punishing people, it makes more sense to me to just schedule the meetings at a time where it's more likely that people *won't* be late. Such as 20-30mins after regular starting hours, so people have a chance to get in, compose themselves after commuting in, maybe grab a cup of coffee and maybe check their emails.

Answer (score 4):

[MrTelly's answer is the most sensible, but let me add to it a bit]

I haven't heard the word "tardy" since kindergarten!

Perhaps everyone who arrives on time should receive a gold star sticker, and anyone who is late doesn't get one. A poster board with everyone's gold stars can be displayed in the lobby so that visitors can easily see who the Good Little Children are.

Seriously, the notion of punishment in a professional environment is ludicrous. People who are late miss out on part of the meeting. If that causes their performance to drop or impacts the project, they get reprimanded *for that*, and eventually fired if the problem isn't corrected.

If you treat your developers like children, don't be surprised if they act like children. And vice-versa.

Comment: Very true. Any good model for leadership (notice how I deftly avoided the word 'management' and went straight for 'leadership' there? big hint) will tell you that praise and appreciation are motivators, whereas fear, punishment, belittlement, etc. are not. It's just bad for business.

Comment: A reprimand is a punishment; it's disciplinary action. Whether it's for the action or its consequences you are advocating punishment for missing daily Scrum. The purpose, as with any punishment, is a negative reinforcement against missing Scrum, which is an essential part of the Scrum development process. The point of being made to hang a rubber chicken around your neck, or any other silly, embarrassing penalty, is to provide that reinforcement without resorting to something that will go on your permanent employment record as a reprimand (or a termination) would.

Comment: The point is that they're *team-decided*; the team agrees on what rules to follow and what embarrassing things they prescribe for the occasional violation to keep themselves honest. As a member of that team, if your opinion is that these types of punishments are stupid and that your preference is managerial reprimands, that opinion should be given weight. Just don't complain when you get a late start due to some household emergency, miss daily Scrum, and are called into the boss's office to sign a written reprimand that goes in your HR file.

Comment: @KeithS: While I appreciate the value of peer pressure and acknowledge the effectiveness of public humiliation (while noting its detrimental psychological effects), the former should be sufficient (though unnecessary) with a team of professionals, while the latter is wholly inappropriate. Hazing is unacceptable, even by majority vote.

Answer (score 3):

It's like a glimpse into the breakdown of a methodology.

Score 1, Rambo

Answer (score 3):

The concept of "punishing" people is ridiculous in my book. If you have people that can't perform the tasks they are being paid to perform, I think you take them aside and find out what's holding them up. Is it the work environment, personal problems, or other? Most of the time there should be some changes that can be made or coaching given that can save somebody from becoming unemployed. If the situation can't be resolved, then terminate the person in a professional manner. But to publicly ridicule somebody, yell at them like children, or force them to pay money for their mistakes? That does nothing to build people up and will probably open you up to lawsuits.

Answer (score 2):

I dislike it in general. When your late to work you boss should punish you not your peers. This is just a really bad idea.

Comment: +1 I hate this almost as much as calling someone Scrum Master

Comment: The punishment is for the person arriving late. Not for the team. The team agrees on the type of punishment.

Comment: I understand that but I do not like the idea of people that are equal to me punishing me for something that they have probably committed themselves thats what bosses are for.

Comment: Too bad I can't +1 @BC. That's is just the worst term ever.

Comment: The whole idea of "punishment" should be alien to the working environment in a modern employer. If people aren't treated like adults where you work, change job.

Comment: If you can't be at a meeting on time you are not behaving like an adult.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, it is to prove a point in the beginning, but if you have to do it more than once, or think long and hard on the punishment, you have the wrong people on your team.

Answer (score 2):

Any work environment where 'punishment' of employees is a valid concept can take a hike.

Oddly, though, the monetary penalty is fine by me.  Apparently, in my mind, that's not a punishment, it's a fine.  I cost other people productivity, theoretically, so I'm okay with that costing me some money.  The others are fundamentally humiliation-based, which is not wise.

Comment: Is it fair to steal someone's actual money for "theoretical" productivity losses? I think any programming environment where being tardy occasionally is grounds to fine monetarily is one to be left. That's just silly.

Comment: I certainly think it's reasonable to feel that way.  I probably would too if it turned out the fine were something like a day's salary rather than a token amount. :)

Answer (score 2):

No one likes these "punishments", but the reality is that the meeting could be at 2pm and people would still be late.  Every office I've worked in has had problems with people (and not *always* the same people) showing up 5 minutes after the meeting has already started.  Sometimes it's because they hit Snooze for "5 minutes" at 5 minutes before the hour.  Some people just aren't considerate enough to show up on time, and it doesn't matter how you punish them.  Sometimes it's because their last meeting ran up until the very end of the hour.  (I try to wrap my own meetings up 5 minutes before the hour, for my own benefit.)

But, having said all that, we put $.50 into a jar for each occurrence and at the end of the iteration someone would walk up to the bakery and buy a pie (typically $5-6) to celebrate the end of the iteration.  So, it was punishment, but at the same time it got us some dessert too.  ;)

Comment: Trivial "punishments" emphasise the triviality of the "offense". If timely attendance is required, stress that it's a condition of continuing employment. If it isn't, then kill the meeting or make it optional.

Comment: I don't disagree. However, the *reality* is that being late for these meetings does not negatively affect people's performance because they just ask other attendees for any relevant missed information later. *This* never leads to people getting fired or managed-out.  Broader problems lead to that.

Comment: Lateness has some impact on productivity. The late attender might miss some relevant information. The only way they could be sure of getting it later is to go to every team member after the meeting and ask them to repeat what they said.

Comment: Really?  I don't think that I've *ever* needed to know all the information in those 10- or 15-minute standups to be able to accomplish my daily goals.  I can't see having to go talk to every team member. (IMHO/IME)

Answer (score 1):

We've got a fun practice that keeps the mood light (for tardiness or any other "offences") but still gets the message through.
If anyone is late to the meeting (which we will invariably start without them) they get a "fine". Fines are recorded and when a person has accumulated 4 fines they have to bring lunch for the team.

We issue fines for other things like your phone ringing (not on silent) during a meeting etc.
It works well to keep the energy up, brings us together as a team, we laugh about it, but the message is clear that some things are unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

The point of these punishments is to make people realize that being at the meeting is important. While scheduling at a time people are likely to be able to make it makes sense, the truth is that some people will always be late if they are allowed to be. Either they have poor time management skills (not uncommon in developers) or they think the meetings are a waste of time and are rebelling in a not-so-subtle way. Either way they are hurting not just themselves but the rest of the team, and there needs to be some way of impressing that on them.

However most developers also resent punishments imposed from above.  What I would suggest is having your team, not you (as scrum-master) decide an appropriate punishment. Then the reluctant attender is responsible to their peers, not under the thumb of authority. In my experience the 'punishments' that work best are those that are irritating enough to be avoided but not difficult or humiliating; maybe fetching a cup of coffee for each other member of the team; monitoring the daily builds for the next day; buying donuts.